# R highcharter - grouped categories - missing label for group with one value only

Tags: r, highcharts, bar-chart, r-highcharter

R Code:

```
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)) 
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rm(list = ls()) 
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load("dplyr","tidyr","highcharter")

raw_data <- read.csv("results.csv")
DT <- data.table(raw_data)

cols <- c('Person','ABC_Capability','ABC_Sub.capability','Leadership.Facet','Facet.Score')
DT <- DT[, cols, with = FALSE]
names(DT) <- c('Person','Capability','Sub_Capability','SVL','Facet_Score')

DT <- dcast(DT, Capability + Sub_Capability + SVL ~ Person, 
            value.var = c('Facet_Score'))

DT1 <- DT %>% 
  group_by(name = Sub_Capability) %>% 
  do(categories = .$SVL) %>% 
  list_parse()


highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Some Title") %>%
  hc_add_series(name="A", data = DT$Joan) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name="B", data = DT$Shane) %>%
  hc_add_series(name="C", data = DT$Simon) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = DT1)
```

Output:

[image]

I tried using a smaller dataset and realized every time there is a single value in a group. The label gets truncated.  For example: Develops people > Empowering

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know much about R, but it seems that it's the same issue as presented in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eLf0rn2q/ If you have only one category on the second level you should remember about representing it as array with only one element. If you pass a String, JS will interpret it as an array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kamil Kulig mentioned, you can try making the ***categories*** an *array* instead of *vector* and it worked for me. Using the sample code you provided, it would be:

```
DT1 <- DT %>% 
  group_by(name = Sub_Capability) %>% 
  # store SVL as array
  do(categories = array(.$SVL)) %>% 
  list_parse()
```

**New Update**:

The vector needs to be converted to an array using the `array()` function even if you are not using grouped categories but simply wanted to rename the tick labels i.e.

```
highcharter::hchart(mtcars[1, ],
                    "column", name = "MPG",
                    highcharter::hcaes(x = 0, y = mpg),
                    showInLegend = F) %>%
    # x axis format
    highcharter::hc_xAxis(title = list(text ="Car Name"),
                          # relabel x axis tick to the name of the cars
                          categories = array(rownames(mtcars)[1]))
```

then the axis tick label will display the name of the car.

[image: When car name vector is converted to an array]

If you use simply `categories = rownames(mtcars)[1])` instead of converting it into an array the x axis label won't display properly:

[image: When car name vector just entered as is]

Here the tick label is just **M** instead of **Mazada RX4**.